# Bias-corrected model from bootstrapped logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap

I'm doing an internal validation of a binary logistic regression model. My goal is to provide clinicians with accurate predictions of baseline risk in untreated patients.  There are no sources of data for an external validation.

My statisticians have run 500 bootstraps and calculated "bias-corrected" predicted probabilities for each subject.  I then asked them for the bias-corrected model and they were not able to produce it, but did send along the intercept and coefficients from each of the bootstraps.

Is it appropriate to calculate the mean or median of these estimates and to create the final model, and would it be correct to call this a "bias-corrected" model?

Additionally, I've seen output from the rms package which returns various original and optimism-corrected estimates from bootstraps (intercept, slope, r-squared, etc) but not the model coefficients.  Can we get these, and if not, should we use the mean or median coefficients?